# Grep command doesn't find the word when a file is divided in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, grep, subprocess

I'm using the module subprocess to call the grep command, where I want to know in which line the word, inserted by the user, is and in which file.

To do this I'm using parallel search where Threads are created. The number of threads is decided by the user, if the number of threads is bigger than the number of files, they are divided. So each thread will read new created files with the same dimension.

In the first few files the word is found but not on every file, even though some of them have that same word in them.

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0owP.png)

```
import subprocess
import threading

(...)

def t_function(args):
    """
    Uses the grep system command using a parallel search for a word inserted by the user in multiple files.
    Requires: args list, with all the files from the user input.
    Ensures: Number of lines in which the word is found as well as its file.
    """
    global contadorFiles
    contadorFiles+=1  
    out = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-nr', text, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    otp = []

    for line in out.stdout: 
            print(line)
            otp.append(line.decode("utf-8").split(":"))

    if otp == []:
            print("Not found in "+args, threading.currentThread().getName())

    for i in range(len(otp)):
            finalN = otp[i][0]
            print('"' + text + '"' + " Found on line " + finalN + " in file " + args, threading.currentThread().getName())
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your idea is to run multiple subprocesses from separate threads? Why? The whole point of a subprocess is that you run it in the background. Why not just start multiple processes and wait for all to complete?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's the task we have in hand. We've already done this using multiple processes, now it has to run with threads

Comment: But if you're running grep, that's automatically a separate process, thread or no thread.